# ¿Por qué razón pasa que quiero sumar 2 importes de una tabla y me las concatena?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Lo que quiero saber es por qué razón pasa ya que les comento. Tengo una tabla en donde tengo diferentes *msisdn* y pueden ser de 2 tipos: *mbb* y *hbb*, entonces cuando seleccionas la oferta carga en una tabla de resumen de pago el importe y los suma. Lo raro es que si agrego un *msisdn* de *mbb* y uno de *hbb* sí me lo suma todo bien y hace el proceso que necesito que haga, pero en el caso de *hbb* se puede o no generar un costo extra, entonces cuando agregas la oferta se van a cargar 2 importes (el del cobro extra y el de la oferta) y solamente cuando es *hbb* me concatena los 2 importes y me sale por ejemplo: 4010 en vez de 50, y como ese total después lo nado hacer otro proceso de pago pues me lo truena por ir 4010.

Les dejo mi código y unas fotos del proceso.

```js
//FUNCION CONSTRUIR TABLA RESUMEN=====================================================================
  function construirTablaResumenCambioProducto(){
    var tarifasEspeciales = $(".checkboxCambioProductoTarifaEspecial").prop("checked");
    var importeTotal      = 0;

    var htmlResumenPago = ""+
      "<tr class='encabezados'>"+
        "<td class='encabezado'>MSISDN</td>"+
        "<td class='encabezado'>IMPORTE</td>"+
      "</tr>";

    $(".paqueteCambioProductoMsisdn").each(function(){

      var idMsisdn = $(this).attr("resultadoId");

      var msisdn   = $(".tablaMsisdnsCambioProducto tr.resultados td.resultado[resultadoId='"+idMsisdn+"'][campo='MSISDN']").attr("digital");

      if(tarifasEspeciales == true){ var importe = $(".paqueteCambioProductoMsisdn[resultadoId='"+idMsisdn+"'] option:selected").attr("tarifaEspecial"); }
      else{ var importe = $(".paqueteCambioProductoMsisdn[resultadoId='"+idMsisdn+"'] option:selected").attr("importeVenta"); }

      var precioMovimiento = $(".paqueteCambioProductoMsisdn[resultadoId='"+idMsisdn+"'] option:selected").attr("precioMov"); 
      var descripcionMovimiento = $(".paqueteCambioProductoMsisdn[resultadoId='"+idMsisdn+"'] option:selected").attr("descMov");

      htmlResumenPago += ""+
        "<tr class='resultados' resultadoId='"+idMsisdn+"'>"+
          "<td class='resultado msisdnCambioProducto'>"+msisdn+"</td>"+
          "<td class='resultado importeCambioProducto'>"+importe+"</td>"+
        "</tr>";

      importeTotal += parseFloat(importe);

      htmlResumenPago += ""+
      "<tr class='resultados' resultadoId='"+idMsisdn+"'>"+
        "<td class='resultado msisdnCambioProducto'>"+descripcionMovimiento+"</td>"+
        "<td class='resultado importeCambioProducto'>"+precioMovimiento+"</td>"+
      "</tr>";

      importeTotal += parseFloat(precioMovimiento);
    });

    $(".tablaResumenPagoCambioProducto").html(htmlResumenPago);
    $(".totalPagarCambioProducto").text("");

    if(importeTotal >= 0){
      if($(globalClaseDivMetodoPago).html() == ""){ $(globalClaseDivMetodoPago).load("<?=$pointer?>forms/busqueda.php?formularioNombre=<?=md5('form_metodo_pago');?>"); }

      $(".totalPagarCambioProducto").text("TOTAL A PAGAR: $"+importeTotal);
    }
    else{ $(globalClaseDivMetodoPago).html(""); }
  }
  //====================================================================================================
  
  
  //FUNCION AVANZAR CAMBIO PRODUCTO=====================================================================
  function clickAvanzarCambioProducto(e){
    var btn = $(e);
    btn.prop("disabled", "disabled");

    var msisdnsOfertas        = new Array();
    var conceptosCobro        = new Array();
    var conceptosCobroConekta = new Array();
    var importePago           = 0;

    var sinOferta = false;
    $(".checkboxMsisdnCambioProducto").each(function(){
      var marcado = $(this).prop("checked");

      if(marcado == true){
        var idMsisdn   = $(this).attr("resultadoId");
        var msisdn     = $(".tablaMsisdnsCambioProducto tr.resultados td.resultado[resultadoId='"+idMsisdn+"'][campo='MSISDN']").attr("digital");
        var oferta     = $(".paqueteCambioProductoMsisdn[resultadoId='"+idMsisdn+"']").val();
        var descOferta = $(".paqueteCambioProductoMsisdn[resultadoId='"+idMsisdn+"'] option:selected").text();
        var idConcepto = $(".paqueteCambioProductoMsisdn[resultadoId='"+idMsisdn+"'] option:selected").attr("idConcepto");
        var importe    = $(".tablaResumenPagoCambioProducto tr.resultados[resultadoId='"+idMsisdn+"'] td.resultado.importeCambioProducto").text();
        console.log(importe);

        importePago    += parseFloat(importe);

        var filaTipoMsisdn = $(".tablaMsisdnsCambioProducto tr.resultados td.resultado[resultadoId='"+idMsisdn+"'][campo='TIPO']");
        var tipoMsisdn   = filaTipoMsisdn.attr("digital");

        if(oferta == "-1"){
          sinOferta = true;
          return false;
        }

        var jsonTempMsisdnsOfertas = {
          "msisdn": msisdn,
          "idOferta": oferta,
          "costo": importe
        }

        if (tipoMsisdn == "MOVILIDAD") {
          var jsonTempConceptosCobro = {
            "idConcepto": idConcepto,
            "importe": importe,
            "detalles": "CAMBIO PRODUCTO",
            "tipoEquipo": "MSISDN",
            "idEquipo": idMsisdn,
            "tipo": tipoMsisdn
          }
        }
        else if (tipoMsisdn == "HBB") {
          var jsonTempConceptosCobro = {
            "idConcepto": idConcepto,
            "importe": importe,
            "detalles": "CAMBIO PRODUCTO HBB",
            "tipoEquipo": "MSISDN",
            "idEquipo": idMsisdn,
            "tipo": tipoMsisdn
          }

          var jsonTempConceptosCobroCambio = {
            "idConcepto": idConceptoCvGlobal,
            "importe": precioCvGlobal,
            "detalles": descripcionCvGlobal,
            "tipoEquipo": "MSISDN",
            "idEquipo": idMsisdn
          }
        }

        msisdnsOfertas.push(jsonTempMsisdnsOfertas);
        conceptosCobro.push(jsonTempConceptosCobro, jsonTempConceptosCobroCambio);

        descOferta = descOferta.split(" ($");
        descOferta = descOferta[0]+" ("+msisdn+")";
        importe    = importe * 100;

        var descripcion = "";

        if (descripcionCvGlobal == "") {
          descripcion = descOferta;
        }
        else{
          var descripcion = ""+descOferta+", "+descripcionCvGlobal+"";
        }

        var jsonTempConceptosCobroConekta = {
          "name": descripcion,
          "unit_price": importe,
          "quantity": 1
        }

        conceptosCobroConekta.push(jsonTempConceptosCobroConekta);
      }
    });


    if(sinOferta == true){
      $(".textoMensaje").text("SE REQUIERE SELECCIONAR LA OFERTA DE TODAS LAS MSISDN MARCADAS.");
      $("#msj").modal("toggle");
      btn.prop("disabled", "");
      return false;
    }

    if(msisdnsOfertas.length == 0){
      $(".textoMensaje").text("SE REQUIERE AL MENOS UN MSISDN PARA CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO.");
      $("#msj").modal("toggle");
      btn.prop("disabled", "");
      return false;
    }

    var formasPago = validacionFormaPago(importePago, conceptosCobroConekta);

    if(formasPago == false){ return false; }

    msisdnsOfertas = JSON.stringify(msisdnsOfertas);
    conceptosCobro = JSON.stringify(conceptosCobro);
    formasPago     = JSON.stringify(formasPago);

    var jsonData = {
      "nroSolicitud": nroSolicitudGlobal,
      "msisdnsOfertas": msisdnsOfertas,
      "conceptosCobro": conceptosCobro,
      "formasPago": formasPago,
      "tokenTarjeta": "",
      "platformType": "CerCrm"
    }

    avanzarProcesoConPago(btn, 3, jsonData);
  }
  //====================================================================================================
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="popupCambioProducto" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modalDialog modalColLg22 modalColMd22 modalColSm22" role="document">
    <div class="modalContent">
      <div class="modalHeader">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modalTitle">Cambio Producto</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modalBody">
        <div class="colLg16 colMd16 colSm24 colXs24 form divTablaCambioProducto">
          <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 encabezadoForm centerText">MSISDNS</div>
          <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 cuerpoForm">
            <div class="colLg06 colMd06 colSm24 colXs24 divCambioProductoTarifasEspeciales">
            </div>
            <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form tabla">
              <table class="tablaMsisdnsCambioProducto">
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="colLg08 colMd08 colSm24 colXs24">
          <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form">
            <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 encabezadoForm centerText">RESUMEN PAGO</div>
            <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 cuerpoForm">
              <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form tabla">
                <table class="tablaResumenPagoCambioProducto">
                </table>
              </div>
              <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 centerText">
                <span class="etiquetaContador totalPagarCambioProducto"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form divMetodoPagoCambioProducto">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="colLg16 colMd16 colSm24 colXs24 form divCambioCoordenadas"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modalFooter clear">
      <div type="button" class="popupBtnCerrar closeCambioProducto" data-dismiss="modal"><div class="cancelar"></div>Cancelar</div>
      <div type="button" class="popupBtnConfirmar" onClick="clickAvanzarCambioProducto(this);"><div class="continuar"></div>Generar</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es "nado"? Por otra parte, no olvides agregar la versión de jQuery que estás utilizando en el snippet, ya que tal como está, no se puede reproducir el problema en la pregunta misma.

Comment: Quizás quizo decir "mando" (?...

Comment: Hola Abdiel, por lo que cuentas, estas sumando 40 + "10", por eso te devuelve "4010", creo que estás tomando "oferta" como cadena, conviértela a número y estará solucionado, @padaleiana nado = mando.

Comment: Será que no estás haciendo la conversión numérica en una de tus variables?... prueba con [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number), por ejemplo `let myvar = Number(...)`